# Daily rsync instead of RAID 1?

Tags: raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, zfsonlinux

I'm building a small home server, and in looking at software and/or hardware RAID1 and RAID5 and ZFS  and whatever, I thought, "what if I just rsync daily between the two internal drives?". What are the cost/benefits of this? I like the idea of keeping the drives independent and easily expandable.

I would have a separate external (cloud) backup of course. Please please don't waste your time telling me RAID1 is not a backup. I know. We all know.

Comment: [Home use servers are not topical on SF](https://serverfault.com/tour). Your home use question exemplifies the reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

Once RAID is configured you have redundancy on storage level. This means, read and write requests are performed from and to 2 drives simultaneously (double IOPS). Also, it means your server/workstation running RAID storage can tolerate a drive failure. In the case of rsync, reads/writes come from/to a single drive, and in case it fails, you will face a system downtime.